# Syntax error, regarding to changing variables in an object from a class

Tags: java, class, variables, object, processing

```
class anyName
{
  int Tcol = 0;
  int fc = 0;
  int x = 0;
  float randx = (random(1, 1000));
  float randy = (random (0, 600));
  int Tsizes = 1;
  {
    if (fc >= x) { //Random Ellipse 3
      stroke (Tcol);
      fill (Tcol);
      ellipse (randx, randy, Tsizes, Tsizes);
    }
  }
}

anyName ranx1 = new anyName();
ranx1.x = 100;
```

Hi, I am trying to add a class/object to my code and it is not working. This is the class I have so far, but when I instantiate one object from that class (ranx1), and then try change one of the variables inside it (x), it says there is a error. Is there anything I need to change? I would really appreciate any help.

Since I instantiated an object from that class, how would I change the variables for the new object? For example, if in the class x = 0, then I made a copy and this time I want x to = 100, but all the other variables such as Tcol and fc to stay the same. I know this is possible because my teacher taught it, but it is not working right now for me.

I am a really newby programmer, so I think this should be easy for someone to answer.

If you want the entire code, please put your email in the answer, so that I can email the entire thing to you.

```
ranx1.x = 100;
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Answer (score 0):

You need a setter in your anyName-class. And then you call the setter:

```
public void setX(int x) {
       this.x = x;
    }
```

and

`ranx1.setX(100)` for example.